# LEGACY_HEADER_MAPPING removed from spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation from Spring Cloud 2020.0.0 (aka Ilford) BWC issue

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We moved to latest Spring Cloud 2020.0.0 (aka Ilford) in our project and when Brave Trace Ids (spanTraceId,spanId etc.. ) passing to Kafka Message it not get extracted by TracingChannelInterceptor because new Jar spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation removed the handling of LEGACY_HEADER_MAPPING from MessageHeaderPropagatorGetter.

Earlier we are using Spring-cloud-sleuth-core jar MessageHeaderPropagation.java to handle extract value of spanId,SpanTraceId etc...

[old extract file](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/2.2.x/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/messaging/MessageHeaderPropagation.java) of core 2.2.X

[New extract file](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/main/spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/messaging/MessageHeaderPropagatorGetter.java) for slueth 3.X.

How to handle these legacy spanId, spanTraceId extraction in Spring Cloud 2020.0.0 (aka Ilford)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. That's a breaking change - we no longer support "X-B3_TraceId" in the headers. You need to  use the new "traceId" approach

Comment: We have 2 application 1 using sleuth 1.2.5 and other using 3.0 . and we need to propagate ( via Spring cloud stream and Kafka message ) spanId and spanTraceId from old to new as 1.2.5 don't know X-B3 fields so I am creating Custom ChannelInterceptor to pass X-B3 fields. Is it correct approach ? or Spring Provide some Bridge or Configuration so that sleuth 1.2.5 can pass both spanId, spanTraceId... and X-B3 fields to new application with sleuth 3.0 ?

Comment: That was the case in Spring Cloud Sleuth 2.x where the headers were deprecated. In Sleuth 3.x we removed those headers